# Efficient sum of Euler's Totient function from 1 to N

Tags: algorithm, math

**Problem summary**

Calculate H when H is defined as follows:

```
H=0;
For (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    For (j=1; j<=n; j++) {
        H = H + totient(i) * totient(j);
    }
}
```

`totient(n)` here is the Euler's Totient function of `n`. The full problem is available [here](https://www.spoj.com/problems/DCEPCA03/).

**Solution summary**

The pseudocode given by the question is a naive way to calculate `H`. After observation, `H` is actually the sum of totient function from `1` to `n`, given `n`, squared. My solution is to generate a list of prime numbers up to `sqrt(10^4) = 10^2` using sieve and generate Euler's Totient function values of number 1 to 10^4 using said sieve to find its prime factor(s) and using [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Then, I only need to sum said calculated values and square it to get `H`.

The code of sieve and calculating Euler's Totient function values is available [here](https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/f1a9e8bad8e4b5c0c2a59766bd8ca168). My code has been accepted by the online judge (after adding the summing part and squaring part which is not included in the code I linked).

**Question**

I noticed something odd in the sum of Euler's Totient function values: `1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 22, 28, 32, 42, 46, 58, 64, 72`, from `i = 1` to `i = 15`. It seems like it could be some custom sequence of mathematics and we can compute the `i-th` Euler's Totient function values directly without summing the Euler's Totient values themselves using some mathematical formula. So I searched Google and found [this](https://oeis.org/A002088).

One particular section I'm interested in is this part:

> Sum_{k=1..n} phi(k) gives the number of distinct arithmetic progressions which contain an infinite number of primes and whose difference does not exceed n. E.g., {1k+1}, {2k+1}, {3k+1, 3k+2}, {4k+1, 4k+3}, {5k+1, ..5k+4} means 10 sequences. - Labos Elemer, May 02 2001

But either the text is poorly formatted or I'm too oblivious in maths that I couldn't understand what it meant. I don't know what the `{1k+1}` etc. means. However, my intuition tells me that it is some sequence and can be formulated by some mathematical function, or at least simplified so that I don't have to calculate Euler's Totient values up to `N`, which I presume will be much faster. Could someone provide a better solution to calculating sum of Euler's Totient function values up to `N`?

Comment: Possibly of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316376/how-to-calculate-these-totient-summation-sums-efficiently

Comment: @גלעדברקן But I **am** already doing that. My sieve can probably be modified to be better as the answer says, but what I'm aiming for is a total different approach of calculating it without calculating the Euler's Totient.

Comment: @Richard Did you knowing [qwr's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316376/how-to-calculate-these-totient-summation-sums-efficiently/1740370#1740370) in that thread which calculates the totient sum up to `n` in time `O(n^(3/4))` without calculating individual totients?

Comment: @btilly Oh sorry, I didn't. I only read the picked answer. I'll read it now.

Answer (score 1):

In OEIS, [A002088](https://oeis.org/A002088) is claimed to be [A005728](https://oeis.org/A005728) minus 1 ("Wolfdieter Lang, Nov 22 2016"). And for A005728 there is some formula ("David W. Wilson, May 25, 2002"):
`a(n) = n(n+3)/2 - Sum(k = 2 to n, a([n/k]))`.

This formula seems to be rather fast.
An unoptimized Python program calculates the first 10000 numbers in about ten seconds.

```py
num = 10000
a = [1] + [0] * num
for n in range(1, num+1):
    a[n] = n * (n+3) // 2
    for k in range(2, n+1):
        a[n] -= a[n // k]
print(a)
```

By the way, note that to calculate the totient function, no fractions are needed, everything can be done with integer arithmetic:

```py
def phi(n):
    prod = n
    for i in set(prime_factors(n)):
        # prod = prod * (1 - 1 / i)
        prod = prod * (i - 1) // i  # rewrite the formula to only work with integers
    return int(prod)
```

PS: I also don't understand the remark by Labos Elemer. It makes me think about the twin prime conjecture, which is still unproven. Anyway, it doesn't give the impression of leading to a fast formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate factorization of a given number *n* then you can find a value of Euler's Totient function quite easily. So let's assume that:

```
n = p1^k1 * p2^k2 * ... * pn^kn
```

Then:

```
H = n * (1 - 1/p1) * (1 - 1/p2) * .... * (1 - 1/pn)
```

For example:

```
n = 24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3
H = 24 * (1 - 1/2) * (1 - 1/3) = 24 * 1/2 * 2/3 = 24 * 1/3 = 8
```

What might be a little bit tricky in the implementation is to use fractions in the calculations instead of decimal numbers. Otherwise you may not receive an integer as the final result.

More information, including the reasoning behind the formula above, can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html).

Comment: But I **am** using that way to solve the problem. My question is not about this.